# OrientDB error when trying to browse a class via console

Tags: java, database, orientdb

I am using OrientDB in an embedded situation in Java. I am creating the database and classes in my application and inserting the data. When I go to view the data through the console, I can see the classes in the database, along with the correct number of rows in the classes. However when I try to browse the data in the class via this command `browse class testData`, I receive the following error

`Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Found invalid % character. Ensure it is opened and closed correctly.`

I have scoured my source data and it does not contain any `%`. I know that OrientDB is sensitive to spacing especially around characters like `)` but again the data that I have does not use the character for which there seems to be an error.

Has anyone run into this kind of error? Any ideas on how to resolve the error?

**Code for creating the database**

```
private void createNewOrientDatabase(){
    String dbPath = "plocal:./db/test";
    orientDatabase = new ODatabaseDocumentTx(dbPath).create();
}
```

**Code for creating the classes**

```
 public void createClasses(Table t){
    if(orientDatabase.getMetadata().getSchema().getClass(t.getName()) == null) {
        orientDatabase.getMetadata().getSchema().createClass(t.getName());
    }
 }
```

**Code for inserting the data**

```
public void insertData(Table table, TableSource data){
    for (String s : data){
        ODocument document = new ODocument(table.getName());
        String[] parts = s.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumns().size(); ++i){
            document.field(table.getColumns().get(i).getName(),parts[i]);
        }
        document.save();
    }
}
```

There are multiple classes but for a give class, the data might look something like this `43840,533,1,1,3,4` just to give you an idea about what the data looks like.

As always, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause of the error...

When I was parsing my source data for the column names, they were in the form `integer name;` and I had forgotten to strip off the `;` from the name. So when I created the field in the document the name had the `;` on the end and this was causing the error when trying to browse the class in OrientDB console.